# Draw angle between straight line and bend line

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw an angle alpha between a straight line and a bend line.
The result can be seen below. However, the desired result is that this angle is somewhat shifted and a bit bended so it fits between ∠BAC.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}

\begin{document}    

\begin{figure}[H]

\begin{tikzpicture}[> = stealth]

    \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (b) at (3,0);
    \coordinate (c) at (3,-1);

    \filldraw [gray] (a) circle (2pt)(b) circle (2pt)(c) circle (2pt);

    \draw[->] (a) to (b);
    \draw[->] (a) [out=7] to (c);
        % [out=9] 

    \node [below] at (0,0) {$A$};
    \node [below] at (3,0) {$B$};
    \node [below] at (3,-1) {$C$};

    % pic[draw, <->, "$\beta$" shift={(-3mm,5mm)}, angle eccentricity=1.2, angle radius=1cm] {angle=a--b--c};
    \draw pic[draw,fill=green!30,angle radius=1cm,"foo" shift={(6mm,1mm)}] {angle=c--a--b};

\end{tikzpicture}

\caption{Angle visualised}
\label{fig:offset_visualised}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Could someone help me with the angle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple way to draw: using `clip` (and without using `angles` or `quotes` library).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}    
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
\path 
(0,0) coordinate (a) node[left]{$A$}
(3,0) coordinate (b) node[right]{$B$}
(3,-2) coordinate (c) node[below]{$C$};
\def\ba{(b)--(a)}
\def\ac{(a) to[out=-10] (c)}
\begin{scope}
\clip \ba--\ac--cycle;
\fill[green] (a) circle(1); 
\end{scope}
\foreach \p in {a,b,c} \fill[orange] (\p) circle(2.5pt);
\draw[<-] \ba; \draw[->] \ac;
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Angle visualised}
\label{fig:offset_visualised}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative (just for comparison) using [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html), wrapped up in `luamplib`.  Here I have used the `subpath` notation and direction features to build a path for the coloured segment directly without resorting to clipping.  Compile with `lualatex`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luatex85}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
z.A = origin;
z.B = 100 right rotated 10;
z.C = z.B shifted 42 down;

forsuffixes $=A, B, C: 
    dotlabel.bot("$" & str $ & "$", z$) withcolor 1/2 white; 
endfor

path a[];
a1 = z.A -- z.B;
a2 = z.A {z.B-z.A} .. z.C;

numeric a, b;
a = arctime 42 of a1;
b = arctime 42 of a2;

path segment;
segment = subpath (0, b) of a2 {direction b of a2 rotated 90} .. 
          {direction a of a1 rotated 94} subpath (a, 0) of a1 .. 
          cycle;

fill segment withcolor 7/8[blue, white];
draw segment withcolor 2/3 blue withpen pencircle scaled 1/4;

interim ahangle := 30;
drawarrow a1;
drawarrow a2;

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If the paths were not to intersect, any drawing code can add an angle easily. The problem is that in the OP's code the arc and the straight line intersect.

Comment: Yes, but I fancied they had not drawn exactly what they wanted...  (which may be a bad assumption on my part)

Comment: Thanks for the clever way of using the `str` macro inside a loop for the labels. I've just made use of it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another MetaPost alternative, using some pre-existing macros from the Metafun format of MetaPost. Also included in a LuaLaTeX program.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luatex85,luamplib}
\mplibsetformat{metafun}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{document}
    \begin{mplibcode}
        u = 3cm; pair A, B, C; A = origin; B = (3u,0); C = u*(3,-1);
        path p[]; p1 = A -- B; p2 = A{right} .. C; 
        beginfig(1);
            labeloffset := 4.5bp;
            forsuffixes P = A, B, C: 
                drawdot P withcolor .8white withpen pencircle scaled 5bp; 
                label.bot("$" & str P & "$", P); 
            endfor;
            anglelength := 1.5u;
            fill buildcycle(p1, anglebetween(p1, p2, "$\alpha$"), p2) withcolor green;
            drawarrow p1; drawarrow p2;
            drawarrow anglebetween(p1, p2, "$\alpha$");
        endfig;
    \end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure angles between curved lines are even defined.  This uses clipping to draw and fill the curved equivalent to the angle pic.

The alternative was to compute angles or use `\pgfpatharcto`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}

\begin{document}    

\begin{tikzpicture}[> = stealth]

    \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (b) at (3,0);
    \coordinate (c) at (3,-1);

    \filldraw [gray] (a) circle (2pt)(b) circle (2pt)(c) circle (2pt);

    \draw[->] (a) to (b);
    \draw[->] (a) [out=7] to (c);
        % [out=9] 

    \node [below] at (0,0) {$A$};
    \node [below] at (3,0) {$B$};
    \node [below] at (3,-1) {$C$};

    % pic[draw, <->, "$\beta$" shift={(-3mm,5mm)}, angle eccentricity=1.2, angle radius=1cm] {angle=a--b--c};
    \begin{scope}
      \clip (a) [out=7] to (c) -- (b) -- cycle;
      \path[very thin,draw=black,fill=green] (a) circle[radius=1cm];
    \end{scope}
    %\draw pic[draw,fill=green!30,angle radius=1cm,"foo" shift={(6mm,1mm)}] {angle=c--a--b};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]